# VueJS Webpack get img path with json data

Tags: json, webpack, vuejs2

I'm using the latest version of the vuejs cli webpack template.
I have a .json file which contains my image names for example: "photo-1.jpg".
 Webpack should convert photo-1.jpg to photo-1.478tp8w3u.jpg for example... when i try to get the correct path for the image in my component i always get errors like: "Module not foun: Error can't resolve...."
My images are in /assets/lab-assets/. They should be processed by webpack.

My component:

```
<template>
     <main>
          <li v-for="item in items">

                <img v-bind:src="itemUrl(item.img)">

          </li>
     </main>
</template>


    <script>

    var $ = require('jquery')
    window.jQuery = $


    export default {

      name: 'djdb',

      data () {

        return {

            items: []

        }

      },

      created() {

          this.fetchData();

      },

      methods: {

        itemUrl (imgName) {

             // return imgName ? require('./lab-assets/' + imgName) : ''
             // error 

             return require('./assets/lab-assets/' + imgName )
            // error

           // return imgName

        },

        fetchData: function () {

            var self = this;


            $.ajax({

                        method: 'GET',

                dataType: 'json',

                url: '/static/data/lab.json'

            })

            .done(function(response) {

                self.items = response;

            })

            .fail(function(data) {

                 .......

            });

        },
      },

    }

    </script>
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to do it:

1. static

move your /assets/lab-assets/ to /static

```
itemUrl (imgName) {
  return `/static/assets/lab-assets/${imgName}`
}
```

2. dynamic by using require.context

```

```
var $ = require('jquery')
window.jQuery = $
const imagePath = require.context('./assets/lab-assets/')

// then 
itemUrl (imgName) {
  return imagePath(imgName, true)
}
```

```